# Telerik GridBoundColumn DataFormatString is ignored

Tags: telerik-grid

I am using a telerik grid, and am trying to format a date column, but it's not working.  The DataFormatString is ignored, no matter what I put in it.

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="myDate" HeaderText="My Date"
            SortExpression="myDate" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"
            UniqueName="myDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="true" />
```

Why is the DataFormatString being totally ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the HTMLEncode property is set to true, the DataFormatString property is ignored.  Since this is a date and you are controlling the format of the output, there's no reason to set the HTMLEncode property anyway.